# How to flip image color data

Tags: color, displacement

I'm using a Black and White image texture for my displacement modifier. The trouble is that the displacement is extruding the white bits when I want the black parts displaced instead. I don't have an app to reverse the colors. Can the values be flipped on Blender?

Comment: There is an "invert" node in the shader editor which does just that. Alternatively use a color ramp and flip the black and white values

Comment: Or use a math node set it to multiply by -1. Or use a color curves node and invert the curve.

Answer (score 2):

@Gorgious is correct, however there is an alternate means to edit your image in Blender that I wanted to share. In Blender load in the image in the UV Editing workspace (ignore any UV wrapping etc). Then go `Image->Invert->Invert image colors`. Then you go `Image->Save As` and now you have an inversed texture which you can directly load in and use as you were previously.

[image]

Result:

[image]